# Client template name is missing in kendo grid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-template

I am working on a kendo grid with a detail template:

[image]

When you edit SC Allocation grid it will show a dropdown list of `ServiceGroup`, when you select from the dropdown and move your mouse away from the grid, the `ServiceGroup` will become empty.

[image]

Here is my main grid code:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<ClientRevenueViewModel>()
    .Name("grid")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(c => c.ClientId)      
        columns.Bound(c => c.Comment).Width(200);
        columns.Command(c => c.Custom("Details").Click("showGraph")).Title("Details").Width(100);
```

Here is my detail grid code:

```
<script id="serviceGroupTemplate" type="text/keno-tmpl">
    @(Html.Kendo().TabStrip()
        .Name("tabStrip_#=ClientId#")
        .SelectedIndex(0)
        .Animation(animation => animation.Open(open => open.Fade(FadeDirection.In)))
        .Items(items =>
        {
            items.Add().Text((cYear - 1 + "/" + cYear) + " Service group allocation ").Content(@<text>
                @(Html.Kendo().Grid<ClientServiceGroupViewModel>()
                    .ToolBar(toolbar =>
                    {
                        toolbar.Create();
                        toolbar.Save().Text("Add service group");
                    })
                    .Editable(e => e.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell))
                    .Name("grid_#=ClientId#") // template expression, to be evaluated in the master context
                    .Columns(columns =>
                    {
                        columns.Bound(o => o.Id).Hidden(true);
                        columns.Bound(o => o.ServiceGroupId)
                            .ClientTemplate("<span style='color:black'>\\#=ServiceGroup\\#</span>")
                            .EditorViewData(new {operatingCenterId = "#=OperatingCenterId#"})
                            .EditorTemplateName("ServiceGroupEditorTemplate")
                            .Title("Service group")
                            .ClientFooterTemplate("Total");
                        columns.Bound(o => o.ServiceGroup).Hidden(true);                           
                    })
                    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                        .Ajax()
                        .Aggregates(ag =>
                        {
                            ag.Add(x => x.Percentage).Sum();
                            ag.Add(x => x.PercentageValue).Sum();
                        })
                        .Events(events => events.Error("error"))
                        .PageSize(5)
                        .Batch(true)
                        .ServerOperation(false)
                        .Read(read => read.Action("GetClientServiceGroup", "ClientAllocatedServiceGroup", new {@clientId = "#=ClientId#"}).Data("getParameters"))
                        .Create(create => create.Action("AddServiceGroupToClient", "ClientAllocatedServiceGroup", new {@clientId = "#=ClientId#", @nextYearBase = "#=NextYearBase#"}).Data("getParameters"))
                        .Update(create => create.Action("UpdateClientServiceGroup", "ClientAllocatedServiceGroup", new {@clientId = "#=ClientId#", @nextYearBase = "#=NextYearBase#" }).Data("getParameters"))
                        .Model(m =>
                        {
                            m.Id(p => p.Id);
                            m.Field(p => p.Id);
                            m.Field(p => p.Percentage);
                            m.Field(p => p.PercentageValue).Editable(false);
                            m.Field(p => p.ServiceGroup);
                            m.Field(p => p.ServiceGroupId);
                        })
                    )
                    .Pageable()
                    .Sortable()
                    //.Events(e => e.Save("checkServiceGroupAllocation"))
                    .ToClientTemplate()
                )
            </text>);
        })
    .ToClientTemplate())
</script>
```

And here is my editor template for dropdown:

```
@model string
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m => m)
    .Name("ServiceGroupId")
    .DataTextField("Name")
    .DataValueField("Id")
    .DataSource(source => source.
        Read(read => read.Action("GetServiceGroupForOperatingCenter", "ServiceGroup", new { @operatingCenterId = ViewData["operatingCenterId"] })))
    .AutoBind(true)
)
```

My only concern is that the service group becomes blank after I select service group from dropdown.

Comment: Your template is `type="text/keno-tmpl"` is an copy&paste problem ?

Comment: yes, maybe a copy paste problem, but it's still working even though the spelling is wrong.